# Regex pattern to strip some invalid JSON elements

Tags: android, regex, json

Thanks for reading!

I am trying to parse a JSON feed in a format like this:

```
(bpjc{"menu": {
                  "id": "file",
                  "value": "File",
                  "popup": {
                    "menuitem": [
                      {"value": "New", "onclick": "CreateNewDoc()"},
                      {"value": "Open", "onclick": "OpenDoc()"},
                      {"value": "Close", "onclick": "CloseDoc()"}
                    ]
                  }
                }})
```

I got error while parsing JSON and after using [JSON Validator](http://www.jsonlint.com/), I figured that `(bpjc` and the closing `)` is not a valid `JSONObject` and so need to strip them out from the feed.

So, I wrote a regular expression as below:

```
        String regex = "\\(bpjc.*\\)";
        String input = "(bpjc{abcd})";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
        System.out.println(matcher.matches());
```

The output is `true` but how do I extract `{abcd}`?

I am referring the [Regular Expressions tutorial](http://regular-expressions.info) but I don't know which pattern applies to my case.

**EDIT:** Adding the [JSON parsing tutorial](http://www.androidcompetencycenter.com/2009/10/json-parsing-in-android/) that I referred. I found it well-explained.

Comment: interesting JSON values.. may i ask what you're doing with this?

Comment: It's a news feed that a regional news client returns in JSON. Wonder what's the logic behind those "special" chars :(

Comment: Since the question mentions "regex" - could someone also post a corresponding "regex" solution so others could use it for knowledge  purposes? Thanks!

Comment: Sagar: Usually this format is jsonp, where bpjc is a function defined on your page already, and will be passed this javascript object.  In that case the result would look like bpjc({}) rather than (bpjc{}) which is why it just looks like a bug on their end.

Comment: @Max: Ahh..I see. Thanks for that info! Learnt something new! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems you are getting an incorrectly formatted JSONP result.  If you know the characters are always going to be there before and after, just do a substring:

`json = json.substring(5, json.length-1)`

Comment: +1 - better than the regex suggested since there are more than one `)` in the string...

Comment: @MByD Although if the string always has the given format then the greedy Kleene star will ensure that it's always the trailing `)` that gets matched.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response! Yes, the format seems to be the same in all JSON results so your solution worked. Curiously though, what could be a corresponding regex for this?

Comment: @Sagar something like `.{5}(.*).{1}` (ie match 5 of any character, followed by any number of characters, followed by one character, with the `()` to capture the middle section.

Comment: @therefromhere - Thanks but I wasn't able to extract the abcd using that regex :(